# Why is US economic data "good" but on-the-ground facts bad?

Tags: recession

I consistently see news articles talking about how great the US economy is doing citing certain metrics.

My field has had massive layoffs over the last two years and a halt in hiring. This is pretty much true across the industry in computer science and electrical engineering sectors. In general job postings for skill-based work has gone down.

Something obviously isn't adding up.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking (since you don’t talk about specific metrics so I just assume your premises are correct), just because economy is doing well does not mean that everyone or every industry is doing well.

For example, if you split economy to let’s say 10 industries according to some criteria (e.g. agriculture, industry, IT etc), and if 9 out of the ten industries experience 30% growth and 1 industry 90% decline you will still see on aggregate data that economy grew by impressive 18% yet for everyone in IT it’s clearly very bad time.

Comment: I haven't seen any growth in my area excluding low-skilled jobs. It's not clear to me what jobs are supposedly growing or industries doing well in these articles. They just assert "jobs added" and "wages up".

Comment: @maxical Same thing that holds for industry can hold for area, if 40 states are experiencing rapid growth but 11 states decline you still will end up with good economy overall